Where a term in a thermodynamics equation popped out of during change of variables
I'm currently reading a paper by Latz and Zausch and came to a change of variables between equations 16 and 17 which confuses me.
For clarity, (16) is
$$
R =- \overrightarrow{q} \cdot \frac{\overrightarrow{\nabla}T}{T} - \overrightarrow{N_+} \cdot \overrightarrow{\nabla}\mu + \overrightarrow{j} \cdot \overrightarrow{E}\tag{16}
$$
And it transforms into (17)
$$
R =- \overrightarrow{Q} \cdot \frac{\overrightarrow{\nabla}T}{T} - \bigg(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial c} \bigg)\overrightarrow{N_+} \cdot  \overrightarrow{\nabla}c + \overrightarrow{j} \cdot \overrightarrow{E}.\tag{17}
$$
Where $\overrightarrow{Q}= \overrightarrow{q} + \overrightarrow{N_+} T (\partial \mu / \partial T).$
So all together, (17) is
$$
R = -\overrightarrow{q} \cdot \frac{\overrightarrow{\nabla}T}{T} - \overrightarrow{N_+} T \bigg(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial T} \bigg)\cdot \frac{\overrightarrow{\nabla}T}{T} - \bigg(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial c} \bigg)\overrightarrow{N_+} \cdot  \overrightarrow{\nabla}c + \overrightarrow{j} \cdot \overrightarrow{E}
$$
Where I believe $\overrightarrow{N_+}T\big(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial T} \big)\cdot \frac{\overrightarrow{\nabla}T}{T}$ simplifies to $\overrightarrow{N_+} \big(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial T} \big)\cdot \overrightarrow{\nabla}T$. If that's incorrect, please say.
To the best of my math knowledge, both $\overrightarrow{N_+} \big(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial T} \big)\cdot \overrightarrow{\nabla}T$ and $\big(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial c} \big)\overrightarrow{N_+} \cdot  \overrightarrow{\nabla}c$ are just a variable change of $\overrightarrow{N_+} \cdot \overrightarrow{\nabla}\mu$ with respect to T and c. But there's also only one $\overrightarrow{N_+} \cdot \overrightarrow{\nabla}\mu$ in (16), while seemingly two of them in (17).
I don't know enough about thermodynamics OR the rules behind changes of variables to be able to tell where the extra term came from, or if I'm wrong somewhere. See linked screenshot to check the equations as they are in the paper. If anyone can explain, I would be super grateful.
